# How to get complex structure from string?

Tags: python, string, dictionary

I'm working on getting complex data structure as "dictionary of list of dictionaries" from a string like that:

```
{ 
    "a": [ {"YY":1, "ZZ":43, "GG":22}, {"YY":33, "ZZ":23, "GG":2}],
    "b": [ {"YY":1, "ZZ":43, "GG":22}, {"YY":33, "ZZ":23, "GG":2}, {"YY":33, "ZZ":23, "GG":2}],
    ...
}
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Is that a JSON file, by chance? If so, look at the built-in `json` module.

Answer (score 2):

One option is to use [`literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval):

```py
from ast import literal_eval
result = literal_eval(my_string)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use python's built-in [`json`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) library for this.

Here is a snippet from python shell.

```
>>> import json

>>> complex_structure=json.loads('{"a":[ {"YY":1, "ZZ":43, "GG":22}, {"YY":33, "ZZ":23, "GG":2}],"b":[ {"YY":1, "ZZ":43, "GG":22}, {"YY":33, "ZZ":23, "GG":2}, {"YY":33, "ZZ":23, "GG":2}]}')

>>> complex_structure
{'a': [{'YY': 1, 'ZZ': 43, 'GG': 22}, {'YY': 33, 'ZZ': 23, 'GG': 2}], 'b': [{'YY': 1, 'ZZ': 43, 'GG': 22}, {'YY': 33, 'ZZ': 23, 'GG': 2}, {'YY': 33, 'ZZ': 23, 'GG': 
2}]}

>>> type(complex_structure)
<class 'dict'>
```